# The extended problem of criterion

Tags: epistemology, definitions

The problem of criterion simply states
 two claims:

> 1. I can only identify instances of knowledge provided I already know what the ?>criteria for knowledge are
> 2. I can only know what the criteria for knowledge are provided I am already >able to identify instances of knowledge.

However, If we can apply these lines of thinking to definitions other than mere 'knowledge'. For example, 'literature' :

> 1. I can only identify instances of literature provided I already know what the >criteria for literature are
> 2. I can only know what the criteria for literature are provided I am already >able to identify instances of literature

we can extend this from questioning the definition of knowledge to questioning the definitions of everything.

Is this extension flawless? If so, what are the explanations toward this statement?

Note: I am a newbie to Philosophy Stack Exchange so if there are any problems in my languages & understanding of concepts please let me know.

Comment: Alas, it can be. This is known as the [Meno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meno#Meno%27s_paradox):"*And how will you inquire into a thing when you are wholly ignorant of what it is? Even if you happen to bump right into it, how will you know it is the thing you didn't know?*" And it extends beyond knowledge to any two interdependent items, and is colloquially referred to as the [chicken-and-egg problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg). In this form the solution also becomes obvious: they both have to develop in conjunction iteratively, as a coupled system.

Comment: Why do you think you wouldn't be able to apply it more broadly?

Comment: thanks for replying and providing information :D / Since I am concerning if there are any logical/understanding problem with my infering.